# Cortana can not close after issuing the command

Tags: uwp, cortana

I have a trouble now. It is that the Cortana canvas is staying open after I complete the voice command in my App Service, and then send a successful message to Cortana. But I don't want the user to deal with the result, I want the Cortana can close itself, So do any one have some good way to resolve this?

Thanks very much.

Comment: check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/voice-commands/interact-with-a-background-app-in-cortana

Comment: Hi Gaurang, I have read this blog, and don't find any way to close Cortana canvas programmatically. Actually we find that if we text-in the commands in the left-bottom corner, then after Cortana responsing a few minutes, the Cortana canvas will close itself, but when we voice the command to Cortana, it will not close itself, even we click anywhere the screen, the Cortana canvas still stays opened unless close it with the "X" button in the top-right corner of it.

Comment: Some body has concern about this?

Comment: ??? any body know about this? Thanks!